# CSS Overflow working on iPad but not iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a div that is supposed to move off the screen when a side navigation is open. This is accomplished by using "margin-left:240px; overflow:auto;". This is working great on my iPad4. But on my iphone5 the div does not go off the screen, instead the contents of the div simply get squished and is visible.

I know overflow has had some issues in the past with iphones/ipads, but not sure why this is working for me on an ipad and not an iphone.

Anyone have any suggestions?